# Rendering nested list with v-for and vue components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to render nested lists with vue components. My approch so far is to create two compontens: One component to render the 'Blog' posts and one component to render the comments. The 'Blogs' are rendering just fine, but the whole 'comments' are missing. I get no errors other than a warning, that I should the lists should have explicit keys. Can someone explain why the 'comments' are not rendering?

```js
var myBlogMainBody = {
    props: ['blog'],
    template: '<div>'+
              '<h3>{{blog.title}}</h3>'+
              '<p>{{blog.content}}</p></div>'
}

var myCommentBody = {
    props: ['comment'],
    template: '<div><h4>Kommentare</h4>' +
              '{{comment.author}}' +
              '<td>{{comment.content}}</div>' /* + 
              '<table><tr><td>Autor</td><td><input v-model="blog.comment.author"></textarea></td></tr>' +
              '<tr><td>Kommentar</td><td><textarea v-model="blog.comment.content"></textarea></td></tr></table>' +
              '<button v-on:click="$emit(`commit-new-comment`,comment)">Kommentieren</button></div>' */
}

var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{ blogEntries:[{
                title: 'Erster Blogeintrag',
                content: 'Hier steht mein Inhalt',
                comments:[{
                    author: 'Henning',
                    content: 'Scheiß blog'
                },{
                    author:'Maike',
                    content: 'Guter Blog!'
                }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Zweiter Blogeintrag',
                content: 'Hier steht mein Inhalt',
                comments:[{
                    author: 'Henning',
                    content: 'Scheiß blog'
                },{
                    author:'Maike',
                    content: 'Guter Blog!'
                },{
                    author:'Maike',
                    content: 'Guter Blog!'
                }]
            }],
            
        },
    methods:{
        addNewBlog: function(blog){
            let newBlog = {
                title: blog.title,
                content: blog.content
            }
            this.blogEntries.push(newBlog);
        }
    },
    components:{
        'my-blog': myBlogMainBody,
        'my-comment': myCommentBody
    }
});
```

```html
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id=app>
        <my-blog v-for='blog in blogEntries'v-bind:blog='blog'>
          <my-comment v-for='comment in blog.comments' v-bind:comment='comment'></my-comment>
        </my-blog>
        
        <create-blog-entry v-on:commit-new-blog='addNewBlog'></create-blog-entry>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myBlog.js"></script>
```

Comment: you should give each blog and comment a unique :key. This could be done by using `<my-blog v-for='(blog, i) in blogEntries'v-bind:blog='blog' :key="blog-${i}">`. Using `:key` is shorthand for `v-bind:key`.

Comment: also `<td>{{comment.content}}</div>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: @SuperDJ Yeah `<td>` was just a leftover, but it doesnt change the result. Why do I need a key? Even if I insert that key it doesnt work..

Comment: My answer should answer that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look below. To add unique keys to your blogs and comments use:

```html
<my-blog v-for='(blog, i) in blogEntries'v-bind:blog='blog' :key="blog-${i}">
```

Where `:key` is a shorthand for `v-bind:key`. So this can be use for `comment` and `blog` as wel. In order to have html of a comment in blog you need to make a blog aware of the comment position by adding a [`slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html). You can also make your components more readable by using [`template ${literals}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals?)

Also note that you have invalid HTML with `<td>{{comment.content}}</div>`.

```js
var myBlogMainBody = {
    props: ['blog'],
    template: `<div>
              <h3>{{blog.title}}</h3>
              <p>{{blog.content}}</p><slot></slot></div>`
}

var myCommentBody = {
    props: ['comment'],
    template: `<div><h4>Kommentare</h4>
              {{comment.author}}
              <div>{{comment.content}}</div></div>` /* 
              '<table><tr><td>Autor</td><td><input v-model="blog.comment.author"></textarea></td></tr>' +
              '<tr><td>Kommentar</td><td><textarea v-model="blog.comment.content"></textarea></td></tr></table>' +
              '<button v-on:click="$emit(`commit-new-comment`,comment)">Kommentieren</button></div>' */
}

var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{ blogEntries:[{
                title: 'Erster Blogeintrag',
                content: 'Hier steht mein Inhalt',
                comments:[{
                    author: 'Henning',
                    content: 'Scheiß blog'
                },{
                    author:'Maike',
                    content: 'Guter Blog!'
                }]
            },
            {
                title: 'Zweiter Blogeintrag',
                content: 'Hier steht mein Inhalt',
                comments:[{
                    author: 'Henning',
                    content: 'Scheiß blog'
                },{
                    author:'Maike',
                    content: 'Guter Blog!'
                },{
                    author:'Maike',
                    content: 'Guter Blog!'
                }]
            }],
            
        },
    methods:{
        addNewBlog: function(blog){
            let newBlog = {
                title: blog.title,
                content: blog.content
            }
            this.blogEntries.push(newBlog);
        }
    },
    components:{
        'my-blog': myBlogMainBody,
        'my-comment': myCommentBody
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
        <my-blog v-for="(blog, b) in blogEntries" :blog="blog" :key="`blog-${b}`">
          <my-comment v-for="(comment, c) in blog.comments" :comment="comment" :key="`comment-${c}`"/>
        </my-blog>
        
        <create-blog-entry v-on:commit-new-blog="addNewBlog"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myBlog.js"></script>
```